# How to create a guest timed Wireless Pass Key

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I already have my home WiFi but I was wondering if it would be possible to create a temporary pass for when the guests come to visit? I would like to give them a password to the network but I would want it to die off after say 30 minutes. Is something like this possible?

PS I can't modify the firmware on the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your router has a feature like that, use that feature. That's always going to be the easiest way.

If your router doesn't have that as a feature, but supports WPA2-Enterprise (WPA2 with 802.1X) and RADIUS, then you could potentially set up a RADIUS server as your authentication server for your wireless network, and if your RADIUS server offered such a feature, you'd be all set. Or you could potentially script your RADIUS server to do what you wanted.

It would mean switching all authentication on your wireless network to Username/Password, rather than the simplicity/convenience of one shared password.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the brand of your router.
If it's Mikrotik, you could make a Virtual AP, set password and vola.
Alot of AP have WPS, so you dont have to give your password, using this and MAC filtration, you could remove MAC address of person you gave access to your network and thats it.
Or simply change your password, gave them it, use MAC address filtration and even if they know your password they won't be able to connect.

This was the easies way without using external servers/services.